# How to SELECT WHERE EXISTS in multi table?

Tags: sql, abap

I have 3 tables:

- `/test/table1`:

  - Columns: `doc_id`, `anotherID`, `value1`
- `/test/table2`:

  - Columns: `anotherID`, `value1`
- `/test/table3`

  - Columns: `doc_id`, `value2`

I want to select the data of `/test/table1` with 2 conditions. One condition in `/test/table2` and another one in `/test/table3`.

So I select my data in one table with one condition like that:

```
SELECT doc_id, anotherID FROM /test/table1 AS d 
      INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @ct_document
      WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM /test/table2 AS a 
                     WHERE value1 < @iv_value1 AND a~value1 = d~value1_id ).
```

It selects the content as I expect. But now I want to add a condition, to only select this data but only `where /test/table3~value2 = 2`.

To do that, I do:

```
SELECT doc_id, anotherID FROM /test/table1 AS d 
          INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @ct_document
          WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM /test/table2 AS a 
                         WHERE value1 < @iv_value1 AND a~value1 = d~value1_id ) 
            AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM /test/table3 AS e 
                         WHERE e~value2 = 2 ).
```

When I do that, I have the same content as before... It doesn't take my second condition.

What don't I understand ?

Comment: Did you try with by changing `AND EXISTS` into `OR EXISTS` in the query?

Comment: Now it select me all the data where the condition 2 is true. I want only to select the data where condition 1 is true + condition 2 is true. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Why don't you do it with INNER JOIN?

Comment: INNER JOIN instead of AND EXISTS ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition `EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM /test/table3 AS e WHERE e~value2 = 2 )` is always evaluated to TRUE if there's at least one line in `/test/table3` with `e~value2 = 2`, whatever the content of the table `/test/table1`.

To make it evaluated to TRUE or FALSE according to `/test/table1` (alias `d`), you should add the condition `AND e~doc_id = d~doc_id`, like this:

```
        ...
        AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM /test/table3 AS e 
                     WHERE e~value2 = 2 AND e~doc_id = d~doc_id ).
```